# how can I make two successive "div" tags not "bleed" into each other?

Tags: css, html

I have two divs:

```
<div style="height:30px; font-weight:bold" align="center">
  <div class = 'membership_description'>
   stuff here, nested <div> etc.
  </div>

 <div style="height:30px; font-weight:bold" align="center">Using Coupon &amp;quot;special-current&amp;quot; - Special access just for current members</div>
```

For some reason, the second div ends up appearing in the middle of all the stuff under the first div.

I tried 'display: block' for the first div but no love, ideas?

**I think I see part of the problem** -- there is this inline style -- when I remove "height" from Google Chrome, it becomes normal.  But I don't have access to that, only css...can I override?

Comment: how is the class membership_description defined? are you sure you didn't forget to close all nested divs?

Comment: I'm not sure I did, part of it is generated from some external systems so I'm trying to figure out how to fix that.

Comment: The example code you gave is either 1 or 3 divs, not 2, unless you didn't close the first one properly... And what do you mean by "there is this inline style"? On one of the nested divs? We need to see more HTML/CSS, or you should try to reduce the problem more (e.g. try creating a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)) that reproduces the problem, if you want us to find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `<div style="clear: both"></div>` under the nested divs

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this is that you aren't clearing your floats properly for your inner nested divs. Try adding `overflow: auto` to `.membership_description`.

Comment: I think I see part of the problem -- there is this inline style -- when I remove "height" from Google Chrome, it becomes normal.  But I don't have access to that, only css...can I override?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `float:left;`  or `float:right;` for both divs, this way they shouldnt overlap each other.  You can also try `<div style="clear: both"></div>` of course.

Answer (score 0):

> I think I see part of the problem -- there is this inline style -- when I remove "height" from Google Chrome, it becomes normal. But I don't have access to that, only css...can I override?

You can override an inline style with the `!important` attribute

```
#element
{
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the `<div>` in `stuff here, nested <div> etc.` is interpreted as a html tag

Comment: I think this is just pseudo stuff to illustrate whats inside there

Comment: well if thats the case, it might be nice to actually post the html and css related to the question